# Adding javascript and css to Magento

Tags: jquery, css, magento

i am new to Magento i wanted to add custom CCS and jQuery to the body of home page , how can i do that ,please some one explain the procedure step by step or can provide me with links?

Comment: i don't know what magento is, but, can you modify the code? or is there some kind of management panel?

Comment: are you using default theme or rwd theme?

Comment: i am using the default theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `local.xml` in your current theme layout folder and add the following code to add custom Js and css on home page only:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>custom.js</script></action> // JS file must be place in Root JS folder
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action> // CSS file must be in current theme folder
        </reference>    
</cms_index_index>  
</layout>
```

If you want to add this CSS and JS on all pages you need to change handler from `<cms_index_index>` to `<default>`